# How can I create unique vertical lines for each facet in my histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display two histograms for scores on a survey, one for female and one for male. Now I want to add vertical lines to display their respective means, but my problem is that with my first approach I have both means displayed in each facet. So i tried to look up solutions and what I have found so far is that I should create a second data frame which contains the means, so I tried using the code I originally used for calculating the means in the first place

```
demo_joined%>%
  filter(!is.na(overall_score))%>%
  group_by(gender)%>%
  summarize(mean_score = mean(overall_score)) -> means
```

Plugging this into the rest of my code for the plot looked like this for me:

```
demo_joined%>%
  filter(!is.na(overall_score))%>%
  ggplot + geom_histogram(aes(overall_score)) +  facet_grid(.~gender) + 
  geom_vline(data = means, xintercept = mean_score)
```

However geom_vline doesnt seem to understand that I want it to look at my means data frame, as the error message is this:

```
Error in new_data_frame(list(xintercept = xintercept)) : 
  object 'mean_score' not found
In addition: Warning message:
geom_vline(): Ignoring `data` because `xintercept` was provided.
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help

Oke sorry this is my first StackOverflow post already wrote everything into the other category, I hope this is fine

Answer (score 2):

Using additional data for the mean is not advised, as complicated things unnecessarily. Instead, you should calculate the mean by using `mutate()` so every observation also shows the group mean. Then you can plot the mean within one command. I made an example with the iris dataset. This should work for you.

```r
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(mean= mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_histogram()+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean), color="red")+
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base version of what Nick made.

```r
library(ggplot2)

species.means <- aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, FUN = mean)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_vline(data = species.means, mapping = aes(xintercept = Sepal.Length), color = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~ Species)
```